# Challenges in beginning with d3.js in a basic rails 4 app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, d3.js

Im trying to use d3 the wonderful Javascript library in a rails 4 app. So far Ive done the following:

1) New rails app with 1 model: "Visualization" attributes: name:string and  description:string
2) Created 1 new visualization 
3) In the views/show.html.erb I have the following code:

```
 <header>
 <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
 <p>
   <strong>Name</strong>
    <%= @visualization.name %>
   </p>

   <p>
     <strong>Description</strong>
     <%= @visualization.description%>
   </p>

   <p>
     <strong>Graph</strong>
   </p>

   </header>

   <body>

   </body>

   <footer>
   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_visualization_path(@visualization) %> |
   <%= link_to 'Back', visualizations_path %>
   </footer>
```

Im using this link [here](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/drawing-divs)

and trying to create the basic bar graph so I added the following to the javascripts/visualizations.js.coffee file

```
 var dataset = [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ];

 d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
     .data(dataset)
     .enter()
     .append("div")
     .attr("class", "bar");
```

Bu when I go to this url:

```
    http://localhost:3000/visualizations/1
```

I see this error screen:

[image]

I would really appreciate it if someone can give a hand with getting started. Thanks

---

UPDATE. The error is gone thanks to the answer below. But Im still unable to understand where this Javascript should go to act on the DOM of the show view template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file name ends with `.coffee` and using `var` in CoffeeScript is invalid. If you want to keep using JavaScript, just rename it to `visualizations.js`.

Comment: Thanks. That took care of the error But now Im confused, where do i have to put this Javascript for it to affect the DOM on the show action view template?